# Independent rotation of stereoscopic cameras

Tags: camera, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, stereoscopy

I have two cameras pointing at the same scene. When they are parallel to each other, I can convert from a real location to each screen coordinate and from two screen coordinates to a real location.

[image]

From a real location to each screen coordinate (the focal f is known):

```
xl = XL / Z * f
yl = 0
xr = XR / Z * f
yr = 0
```

From two screen coordinates to a real location:

```
XL + XR = D
xl / f = XL / Z
xr / f = XR / Z

Z = f * D / (xl + xr)
XL = xl / f * Z
YL = yl / f * Z
```

The cameras have now two independent three-axis rotations (α, β, ζ) and (α', β', ζ'). This is really their yaw, pitch and roll. The camera first rotates of α along the y axis, then it rotates of β along its new x axis and finally rotates of ζ along its new z axis.

I can still convert from a real location to each screen coordinate by rotating the real position and applying the same formula as the case above:

```
(AL, BL, CL) = rot33_axis3(ζ) * rot33_axis1(β) * rot33_axis2(α) * (XL, YL, Z)
(AR, BR, CR) = rot33_axis3(ζ') * rot33_axis1(β') * rot33_axis2(α') * (XR, YR, Z)
xl = AL / CL * f
yl = BL / CL * f
xr = AR / CR * f
yr = BR / CR * f
```

I have tested and the calculated coordinates match the screen.

**My problem now is to calculate the real location from the 2 screen coordinates.** I'm doing:

```
(al, bl, cl) = rot33_axis2(-α) * rot33_axis1(-β) * rot33_axis3(-ζ) * (xl, yl, f)
(ar, br, cr) = rot33_axis2(-α') * rot33_axis1(-β') * rot33_axis3(-ζ') * (xr, yr, f)

XL + XR = D
al / f = XL / Z
ar / f = XR / Z

Z = f * D / (al + ar)
XL = al / f * Z
YL = bl / f * Z
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

My idea is to take the screen coordinate, assign the z value to the focal, apply the rotation matrices in reverse order with negative angles (at this moment, the screen have rotated "back" to planes parallel to the line joining the two cameras) and apply the same formula as in the first case.

What am I doing wrong? Is it wrong to start with (xl, yl, f)?

**EDIT 1:**

Based on aledalgrande anwer, Here is some opencv code:

```
//Image is 640x360, focal is 0.42
Matx33d camMat = Matx33d(
0.42f * 640.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f,
0.0f, 0.42f * 360.0f, 180.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Matx41d distCoeffs = Matx41d(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Matx31d rvec0, tvec0, rvec1, tvec1;

solvePnP(objPoints, imgPoints0, camMat, distCoeffs, rvec0, tvec0);
solvePnP(objPoints, imgPoints1, camMat, distCoeffs, rvec1, tvec1);
//Results make sense if I use projectPoints

Matx33d rot0;
Rodrigues(rvec0, rot0);
Matx34d P0 = Matx34d(
rot0(0, 0), rot0(0, 1), rot0(0, 2), tvec0(0, 0),
rot0(1, 0), rot0(1, 1), rot0(1, 2), tvec0(0, 1),
rot0(2, 0), rot0(2, 1), rot0(2, 2), tvec0(0, 2));

Matx33d rot1;
Rodrigues(rvec1, rot1);
Matx34d P1 = Matx34d(
rot1(0, 0), rot1(0, 1), rot1(0, 2), tvec1(0, 0),
rot1(1, 0), rot1(1, 1), rot1(1, 2), tvec1(0, 1),
rot1(2, 0), rot1(2, 1), rot1(2, 2), tvec1(0, 2));

Point u0_(353, 156);
Point u1_(331, 94);

Matx33d camMatInv = camMat.inv();
u0.x = u0_.x * camMatInv(0, 0) + u0_.y * camMatInv(0, 1) + 1.0f * camMatInv(0, 2);
u0.y = u0_.y * camMatInv(1, 0) + u0_.y * camMatInv(1, 1) + 1.0f * camMatInv(1, 2);
u1.x = u1_.x * camMatInv(0, 0) + u1_.y * camMatInv(0, 1) + 1.0f * camMatInv(0, 2);
u1.y = u1_.y * camMatInv(1, 0) + u1_.y * camMatInv(1, 1) + 1.0f * camMatInv(1, 2);

Matx14d A1(u0.x * P0(2, 0) - P0(0, 0), u0.x * P0(2, 1) - P0(0, 1), u0.x * P0(2, 2) - P0(0, 2), u0.x * P0(2, 3) - P0(0, 3));
Matx14d A2(u0.y * P0(2, 0) - P0(1, 0), u0.y * P0(2, 1) - P0(1, 1), u0.y * P0(2, 2) - P0(1, 2), u0.y * P0(2, 3) - P0(1, 3));
Matx14d A3(u1.x * P1(2, 0) - P1(0, 0), u1.x * P1(2, 1) - P1(0, 1), u1.x * P1(2, 2) - P1(0, 2), u1.x * P1(2, 3) - P1(0, 3));
Matx14d A4(u1.y * P1(2, 0) - P1(1, 0), u1.y * P1(2, 1) - P1(1, 1), u1.y * P1(2, 2) - P1(1, 2), u1.y * P1(2, 3) - P1(1, 3));

double normA1 = norm(A1), normA2 = norm(A2), normA3 = norm(A3), normA4 = norm(A4);

Matx44d A(
A1(0) / normA1, A1(1) / normA1, A1(2) / normA1, A1(3) / normA1,
A2(0) / normA2, A2(1) / normA2, A2(2) / normA2, A2(3) / normA2,
A3(0) / normA3, A3(1) / normA3, A3(2) / normA3, A3(3) / normA3,
A4(0) / normA4, A4(1) / normA4, A4(2) / normA4, A4(3) / normA4);

SVD svd;
Matx41d u;
svd.solveZ(A, u);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the simplified formula for triangulation if the cameras are rotated ([general case](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~iocchi/stereo/triang.html)). You will have to resort to [linear triangulation](http://bardsley.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/3d-reconstruction-using-the-direct-linear-transform.pdf) (or [other methods](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/triangulation/triangulation.pdf) if you want a more accurate result).

```
// points u0 and u1, projection matrices firstP and secondP

// "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" 12.2 and 4.1.1
cv::Matx14d A1 = u0(0) * firstP.row(2) - firstP.row(0);
cv::Matx14d A2 = u0(1) * firstP.row(2) - firstP.row(1);
cv::Matx14d A3 = u1(0) * secondP.row(2) - secondP.row(0);
cv::Matx14d A4 = u1(1) * secondP.row(2) - secondP.row(1);

double normA1 = cv::norm(A1), normA2 = cv::norm(A2), normA3 = cv::norm(A3), normA4 = cv::norm(A4);

cv::Matx44d A(A1(0) / normA1, A1(1) / normA1, A1(2) / normA1, A1(3) / normA1,
              A2(0) / normA2, A2(1) / normA2, A2(2) / normA2, A2(3) / normA2,
              A3(0) / normA3, A3(1) / normA3, A3(2) / normA3, A3(3) / normA3,
              A4(0) / normA4, A4(1) / normA4, A4(2) / normA4, A4(3) / normA4);

cv::SVD svd;
cv::Matx41d pointHomogeneous;
svd.solveZ(A, pointHomogeneous);
```

Comment: Thanks. Both cameras are at 45 degrees (not a small angle) of the main line between the two cameras. They both point towards a middle line between the two cameras. Then the pitch and roll angles are small. Will the linear triangulation be enough? Is there a pseudo implementation somewhere?

Comment: Yes linear triangulation encompasses any combination of poses. There is an implementation in OpenCV or you can just very simply construct the system with the two point coordinates as explained in the paper and then solve for the SVD.

Comment: I accept your answer and it was very helpful. I have three or four real points with their matching screen coordinates on both views. I understand that there is no fixed formula. Is there somewhere the implementation or pseudo algorithm of the algo to calculate the real point location? It's not easy to read opencv because of all the framework layers and function helpers. Perhaps there is a git source somewhere that does the job simply.

Comment: I added the code, but I really suggest you understand why it works like that. You can see the theory in the book named at the top. I used OpenCV for matrices and SVD, but you can very well use Eigen too. Also remember you will have better results if you pass normalized points.

Comment: I'm close but still not working. I got the cameras extrinsics through solvePnP and the resulting matrices make sense if I use projectPoints. I calculate the projection matrices with Rodrigues but I'm confused how I should include the intrinsic matrix. See my answer below.

Comment: If you want to unproject your points to normalized coordinates, multiply the points by it, e.g.: `u0_euclidean = camMatInv * u0_`

Comment: But this is what I'm doing in the opencv code :-) Am I missing something? The result 3d point as a Matx41d still doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes, it is the same, just short version. That Matx41d is the [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) 3D point, to get the euclidean point just divide the first 3 coordinates by the last, those will give you the point you want.

Comment: Still not working. Very strange. Either there is a stupid mistake somewhere or something is wrong. I have posted the code and the two images here: http://www.gentil.com/tmp/3dreconstruction.zip

Comment: It's working now. There were some typos in my code. I have fixed it in the edit of the question. Thanks!